# ytdl() error: The "url" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined

Tags: ytdl

I'm experiencing an issue with both **ytdl( )** and **downloadFromInfo( )** functions.

Error:

> ```
> TypeError_ [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "url" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
>
> at validateString (internal/validators.js:107:11)
> at Url.parse (url.js:155:3)
> at Object.urlParse [as parse] (url.js:150:13)
> at doDownload (E:\Discord Bots\Astralis Time 2\node_modules\miniget\dist\index.js:90:28)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
> ```

In the case of **ytdl( )** I checked if my input was incorrect, but it wasn't. I believe there may be a problem when ytdl-core tries to read the object from the **getInfo( )** function.

With some videos it does work, but those cases are rare.

This is the code I use, I have checked all my variables, including songInfo and they all seem to be correct, the error only appears when I run **ytdl( )** or **downloadFromInfo( )**.

```
async function playSong(channela, message){
var songInfo;
var songTitle;
let connection;
let dispatcher;

if(typeof servers[message.guild.id].queue[0] === 'undefined' || !servers[message.guild.id].queue[0] || typeof servers[message.guild.id].queue[0] !== 'string'){
    servers[message.guild.id].queue.shift();
    if(!servers[message.guild.id].queue[0]){
        connection.disconnect();
        message.member.voice.channel.leave();
    }
}
try{
    songInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(servers[message.guild.id].queue[0]);
    songTitle = songInfo.title;
    connection = await channela.join();
    let stream = await ytdl.downloadFromInfo(songInfo, {filter: 'audioonly', quality: 'highestaudio', highWaterMark: 1<<25});
    dispatcher = await connection.play(stream, {highWaterMark: 1});
}catch(error){
    console.error('Could not play the video:' + error);
    message.channel.send('**Please, try again.**');
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me the trick was to globally uninstall the package and install it back.

```
> npm uninstall -g ytdl-core --save
> npm install ytdl-core
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to manually update ytdl-core, for some reason, **npm install ytdl-core@latest** didn't update the module.